# Consumer not listen message from retry topic

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka, consumer

I use Spring-Kafka 2.7.7 with @RetryableTopic to re-process messages from my two topics, ***MyTopic1*** and ***MyTopic2***, after some time

```
@RetryableTopic(
    attempts ="3",
    backoff = @Backoff(delay=1000),
    autoCreateTopics = "false")
)
@KafkaListener(topics = "myTopic1",
public void processMessage(MyPojo1 message) {
   // ... message processing
}

@RetryableTopic(attempts ="3",
                backoff = @Backoff(delay=1000),
                autoCreateTopics = "false"))
@KafkaListener(topics = "myTopic2")
public void processMessage(MyPojo2 message) {
   // ... message processing
}

@DltHandler
public void DltHandler1(MyPojo1 message) {
    // ... message processing
}

@DltHandler
public void DltHandler1(MyPojo2 message) {
    // ... message processing
}
```

I have Retry-Mytopic1-0, Retry-Mytopic1-1, Retry-Mytopic1-2, MyTopic1-DLT and Topic for MyTopic2
But I have two problems

1. After writing a message to the Topik Retry-Mytopic1-0, I get a
   message:

   *Seek to Current AFTER Exception; NESSTED Exception is
   org.springframework.kafka.listenerexecitationfailedException:
   Listener Failed; NESSTED Exception is
   org.springframework.kafka.listener.kafkabackoffexception: Partition
   0 from Topic Retry-Mytopic1-0 is not Ready for Consumption, Backing OFF
   For Approx. 990 Millis.*

   And that's right, the consumer saw that the processing time did not
   occur But in the future, processing does not occur, on this
   information message everything ends
2. How can I configure @dlthandler for each DLT-Topic? After all, they
   get different DTO in the input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. 2.7.x is no longer supported; upgrade to a supported version (2.9.12 or later) and report back if you still see a problem. Otherwise, DEBUG logging might help you. https://spring.io/projects/spring-kafka#support
2. You would have to put each listener in its own class to have multiple DLT handlers.

Comment: its work, tnx! May be you can help me with another question - how I can use a method from the field from class *ConfigurationProperties* in *RetryableTopic* in *attempts*? I mean I have *List* field and I want use *size()* for *attempt*

Comment: Don't ask new questions in comments; it is not clear what you mean; ask a new question showing code, configuration, and exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I will do so